# How to change the comment sign for m4's --synclines option?

Tags: assembly, preprocessor, m4, picoblaze

I'm using `m4` preprocessor with the command line option `--synclines`. This option emits `#line <nn>` lines after each expanded multi line.

Example:

```
; sr0(<register>, <count>) unrolls the sr0 statement for <register> <count> times.
sr0(reg_0, 3)
sr1 reg_1
```

Result:

```
#line 1 "test.psm"
; sr0(<register>, <count>) unrolls the sr0 statement for <register> <count> times.
sr0 reg_0
#line 2
sr0 reg_0
#line 2
sr0 reg_0
#line 2
sr1 reg_1
```

Because sr0(reg_0, 3) was originated in line 2, m4 adds `#line 2` after each expansion.

**How can I change the comment sign `#` to `;`?**, because the assembler does not support `#` as a comment sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `sed`, assuming the code produced by `m4` is in `test.psm`:

```
$ sed 's/^#/;/' <test.psm
;line 1 "test.psm"
; sr0(<register>, <count>) unrolls the sr0 statement for <register> <count> times.
sr0 reg_0
;line 2
sr0 reg_0
;line 2
sr0 reg_0
;line 2
sr1 reg_1
```

Comment: I would like to get a m4-only solution. Running a second processing step with sed or other tools is possible, but this is not the wished solution, because it involves a second tool, temp files or stdin/stdout pipelining.

Comment: An `m4`-only solution would be possible by using `m4` to replace `#line` with `;line`, but that would require a) using `changeword` to allow the use of macros that include `#` in their names (which is experimental and so not always available, and it is subject to change if it is available), and b) it would require piping the output from `m4` into a second instance of `m4` to change `#line` to `;line` (which involves using pipelining, which you would like to avoid).

Comment: I see no way to change the synclines output using `m4`'s command line parameters but given that `m4` is free software, you could modify the source and re-compile a custom version of `m4` that output `;line` rather than `#line` for the synclines. Unless using a pipeline is simply impossible in your context, I wouldn't recommend this approach and would recommend using a pipeline instead.

Comment: `changecom(;)` is already active, but has no effect on synclines. Is this a bug?

Comment: Using `changecom` will change the comment character for input to `m4` but not output, unfortunately.