How to disable m4 --synclines for code region?
m4 has an useful option --synclines that outputs #line lines to synchronize output. However, this option breaks C macro definition. Consider the following source file:
#define MACRO  blabla \
    ifelse(`', `', `dnl
    a \
    b \
    ', `dnl
    c \
    d \
    ') \
    /* */

It results in the following with --synclines:
+ /bin/bash -c 'm4 -sg test.m4'
#line 1 "test.m4"
#define MACRO  blabla \
                a \
#line 2
        b \
#line 2
         \
#line 9
        /* */

And without synclines:
+ /bin/bash -c 'm4 -g test.m4'
#define MACRO  blabla \
                a \
        b \
         \
        /* */

The resulting #line lines inside a macro definition result in an invalid C file that can't be compiled.
Is it possible to temporarily disable synclines for specific lines in m4?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30028502/1216776

Yea, I could  like sed -z 's/\\\n#line[^\n]*\n/\\\n/' remove #lines after a \ . Still sad. Is there a m4 mailing list? http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/m4-discuss from https://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group=m4 results in 404 not found error.

What does m4 do that you can't do with the C preprocessor?  Don't all C compilers have __LINE__ or equivalent?

hi @stark What does m4 do that you can't Where do I start?! Executing external commands? Iterating over list of lists of arguments? Ability to generate C preprocessor macros definitions? Or just the ability to compare strings? It's much much more readable for generating templated C code than using C preprocessor. I throw an example. While you can do that in C preprocessor, using m4 makes it more maintainable. Do you feel like C preprocessor is always what you need? LINE is available always
